# Using str_replace in a list, and iterate over all elemnts

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, str-replace, gsub

What is a good way to replace a certain character in a list in R? I tend to prefer  the tidyverse functions str_replace_all and map, but I can also use base functions gsub and lapply.

Lets create a list:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(iris) 
df2 <- as.data.frame(iris) 
df3 <- as.data.frame(iris) 

iris_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want to replace all mentions to "virginica" to "flower". So I create a custom function:

```
my_fun <- function(my_list){
  str_replace_all(my_list, pattern = "virginica", replacement = "flower")
}
```

The function str_replace needs a vector as its input. But when I try to use map to iterate over the elements of the list, I get an error: "argument is not an atomic vector; coercing"

```
map(.x = iris_list, .f = my_fun)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(iris_list, ~ mutate(.x, Species = str_replace(Species, "virginica", "flower")))
```

Comment: The "mutate" function was missing, and I did not specify where to pass the function (the vector "species"). Your answer is good for me.